# Python Lista inverter Valores

Tags: python, lista

Estou tentando inverter dois valores dentro de uma lista aninhada. Exemplo: Na lista da lista há dois valores `[[1,11],[2,22],[3,33],[4,44]]` e gostaria de inverter os valores para `[[11,1],[22,2],[33,3],[44,4]]`.

O erro que recebo:

> ```
> IndexError: list assignment index out of range
> ```

```
def inverte_valores():

    lista = [[1,11],[2,22],[3,33],[4,44]]
    maior_numero = len(lista)
    reordenar_lista = [[] * 2] * maior_numero
    primeira_posicao = 0
    for primeira_posicao in range(maior_numero):
        reordenar_lista[primeira_posicao][0] = lista[primeira_posicao][1]
        reordenar_lista[primeira_posicao][1] = lista[primeira_posicao][0]
    print(reordenar_lista)

    return reordenar_lista


inverte_valores()
```

Comment: Desta maneira as duas posições ficarão com os valores iguais. Utilize uma variável auxiliar para fazer a troca.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não precisa trocar os elementos desta maneira. E se a lista tiver mais de 2 elementos?

Neste caso, basta usar [`reversed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) para inverter as listas:

```
lista = [[1,11],[2,22],[3,33],[4,44]]

inversos = []
for e in lista:
    inversos.append(list(reversed(e)))

print(inversos) # [[11, 1], [22, 2], [33, 3], [44, 4]]
```

Se quiser, pode trocar o *loop* por uma [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=list%20comprehension#list-comprehensions), bem mais sucinta e [*pythônica*](/q/192343/112052):

```
inversos = [ list(reversed(e)) for e in lista ]
```

Ou ainda:

```
inversos = [ e[::-1] for e in lista ]
```

`[::-1]` usa a sintaxe de [*slicing*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3940137) para inverter a lista.

---

Mas se quiser muito usar os índices, faça assim (e só vai funcionar se todas as sub-listas tiverem exatamente 2 elementos):

```
inversos = []
for e in lista:
    inversos.append([e[1], e[0]])
```

Comment: Obrigado hkotsubo!!! As suas duas versões versões pythônica funcionaram perfeitamente.Fiquei matutando o motivo do erro da minha versão, mas não teve jeito. Então, resolvi postar a dúvida aqui. Obrigado

Answer (score -3):

Analisando o programa abaixo verifica-se, que você cria varias redundâncias que atrapalham a logica do programa.

```
def inverte_valores():

 lista = [[1,11],[2,22],[3,33],[4,44]]
 maior_numero = len(lista)
 ** redundância (cria sublista na lista reordenar_lista)**
 > reordenar_lista = [[] * 2] * maior_numero
 ** redundância (variavel: primeira_posicao)**
 > primeira_posicao = 0 # subtence o valor inicial 0
   for primeira_posicao in range(maior_numero):
        reordenar_lista[primeira_posicao][0] = lista[primeira_posicao][1]
        reordenar_lista[primeira_posicao][1] = lista[primeira_posicao][0]
 ** redundância (print e return)**
 > print(reordenar_lista)
 > return reordenar_lista
inverte_valores()
```

> Solução:

```
  def inverte_valores():
  lista = [[1,11],[2,22],[3,33],[4,44]]
  maior_numero = len(lista)
  reordenar_lista = [] * maior_numero
  for primeira_posicao in range(maior_numero):
      reordenar_lista += [[lista[primeira_posicao][1], lista[primeira_posicao][0]]]
  return reordenar_lista
inverte_valores()
```

Comment: O seu algoritmo continua contendo redundâncias. Pode ser simplificado para isso https://ideone.com/TEJFrS